# Working out what was matched by each part of a regex

Tags: python, regex, grammar, text-parsing

I have a few hundred (fairly simple) regular expressions and their matches within a large number of sequences. I would like to be able to tell what part of each regex matches what position in the target sequences. For example, the following regex “[DSTE][^P][^DEWHFYC]D[GSAN]” may be matched by positions 4 to 8 in the following sequence:

ABC**SGADA**ZZZ

What I would like to get out (programmatically) is, for each regex, 1) each 'part' of the regex and 2) the position in the target sequence that was matched by it:

```
[DSTE] -- (3, 4),
[^P] -- (4, 5),
[^DEWHFYC] -- (5, 6),
D -- (6, 7),
[GSAN] -- (7, 8)
```

I found this website which essentially does what I want: https://regex101.com/, but I’m not sure how deep into regex parsing I would have to dive to be able to do this in my own code (I'm using Python and R).

Comment: Match the whole sequence in a text with a simpler regex (e.g. `\b[A-Z]+\b`) and use your expression on the found string afterwards.

Comment: Do the "parts" always just match one character? If not, how do you know what is a "part"?

Comment: I imagine they should be single characters unless they're repeats or explictly grouped but I'm not sure if this covers all the possible scenarios (not sure how the website I've linked breaks down each regex, either).

Comment: It's really up to you to decide how you need the match split up. For patterns like the one in your question, it's easy. But in more complicated regexes, it might even be ambiguous.

Comment: I think there must be some built-in notion of a token within each implementation of regex parsing. I guess part of my question is how to access the internal of the built-in parser without having to implement a parser of my own.

Comment: My advice: don't use regexes, they look really simple until you need to do something slightly different and then they're impossible to work with. Computationally they're an incredibly complicated way to solve what is almost always a simpler problem. Look into ways to use dynamic programming techniques instead, what you find there is going to be more flexible, easier to reason about, easier to add features to, etc.

Comment: @voutasaurus Thanks -- it's not clear from the post but what I'm trying to do is analyse existing regexs (and their matches) from a biological database that goes back almost twenty years. Clearly there are limitations to this representation but I think I'm stuck with it for the time being.

Comment: Try absorbing information about how regex works under the hood. Might help expand the set of tools you're bringing to the problem: https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not 100% but I returned outputs on 3365/3510 of my dataset. The few I checked lined up :)

Included in my github (Linked below) are the inputs and outputs in csv, txt (respectively).

Please ignore the global variables; I was considering switching the code over to see if there was a noticeable improvement with the speed but didn't get around it.

Currently this version is having trouble with order of operations regarding the *alternation* and the start/end line operators (^ $) if they are options for alternation at the beginning or end of the string. I'm pretty confident it has to do with precedent; but I wasn't able to get it organized well enough.

The function call for the code is in the last cell. Instead of running the entire DataFrame with

```
for x in range(len(df)):

try:
    df_expression = df.iloc[x, 2]
    df_subsequence = df.iloc[x, 1]

    # call function
    identify_submatches(df_expression, df_subsequence)
    print(dataframe_counting)
    dataframe_counting += 1
except:
    pass
```

You can easily test one at a time by passing a pattern and a corresponding sequence to the function like this:

```
p = ''
s = ''

identify_submatches(p, s)
```

Code:
https://github.com/jameshollisandrew/just_for_fun/blob/master/motif_matching/motif_matching_02.ipynb

Inputs:
https://github.com/jameshollisandrew/just_for_fun/blob/master/motif_matching/elm_compiled_ss_re.csv

Outputs:
https://github.com/jameshollisandrew/just_for_fun/blob/master/motif_matching/motif_matching_02_outputs.txt

```
"""exp_a as input expression
       sub_a as input subject string"""

    input_exp = exp_a
    input_sub = sub_a

    m_gro = '\^*\((?:[^()]+|(?R))*+\)({.+?})*\$*'
    m_set = '\^*\[.+?\]({.+?})*\$*'
    m_alt = '\|'
    m_lit = '\^*[.\w]({.+?})*\$*|\$'


    # PRINTOUT
    if (print_type == 1):
        print('\nExpression Input: {}\nSequence Input: {}'.format(exp_a, sub_a))

    if (print_type == 3):
        print('\n\nSTART ITERATION\nINPUTS\n  exp: {}\n  seq: {}'.format(exp_a, sub_a))


    # return the pattern match (USE IF SUB IS NOT MATCHED PRIMARY)
    if r.search(exp_a, sub_a) is not None:
        m = r.search(exp_a, sub_a)
        sub_a = m.group()
        # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
        if print_type == 3:
            print('\nSEQUENCE TYPE M\n  exp: {}\n  seq: {}'.format(exp_a, sub_a))

        elif m is None:
            print('Search expression: {} in sequence: {} returned no matches.\n\n'.format(exp_a, sub_a))
            return None

    if (print_type == 1):
        print('Subequence Match: {}'.format(sub_a))



    # check if main expression has unnested alternation
    if len(alt_states(exp_a)) > 0:
        # returns matching alternative
        exp_a = alt_evaluation(exp_a, sub_a)

        # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
        if print_type == 3:
            print('\nALTERNATION RETURN\n  exp: {}\n  seq: {}'.format(exp_a, sub_a))


    # get initial expression list
    exp_list = get_states(exp_a)


    # count possible expression constructions
    status, matched_tuples = finite_state(exp_list, sub_a)

    # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
    if print_type == 3:
        print('\nCONFIRM EXPRESSION\n  exp: {}'.format(matched_tuples))


    # index matches
    indexer(input_exp, input_sub, matched_tuples)


def indexer(exp_a, sub_a, matched_tuples):

    sub_length = len(sub_a)
    sub_b = r.search(exp_a, sub_a)
    adj = sub_b.start()
    sub_b = sub_b.group()

    print('')

    for pair in matched_tuples:
        pattern, match = pair

        start = adj
        adj = adj + len(match)
        end = adj
        index_pos = (start, end)

        sub_b = slice_string(match, sub_b)
        print('\t{}\t{}'.format(pattern, index_pos))

def strip_nest(s):

    s = s[1:]
    s = s[:-1]

    return s

def slice_string(p, s):

    pat = p
    string = s

    # handles escapes
    p = r.escape(p)
    # slice the input string on input pattern
    s = r.split(pattern = p, string = s, maxsplit = 1)[1]


    # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
    if print_type == 4:
        print('\nSLICE STRING\n  pat: {}\n  str: {}\n  slice: {}'.format(pat, string, s))


    return s

def alt_states(exp):
    # check each character in string
    idx = 0 # index tracker
    op = 0 # open parenth
    cp = 0 # close parenth
    free_alt = [] # amend with index position of unnested alt

    for c in exp:
        if c == '(':
            op += 1
        elif c == ')':
            cp += 1
        elif c == '|':
            if op == cp:
                free_alt.append(idx)
        if idx < len(exp)-1:
            idx+=1

    # split string if found
    alts = []

    if free_alt:
        _ = 0
        for i in free_alt:
            alts.append(exp[_:i])
            alts.append(exp[i+1:])

    # the truth value of this check can be checked against the length of the return
    # len(free_alt) > 0 means unnested "|" found
    return alts


def alt_evaluation(exp, sub):

    # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
    if print_type == 3:
        print('\nALTERNATION SELECTION\n  EXP: {}\n  SEQ: {}'.format(exp, sub))

    # gets alt index position
    alts = alt_states(exp)

    # variables for eval
    a_len = 0 # length of alternate match
    keep_len = 0 # length of return match
    keep = '' # return match string

    # evaluate alternatives
    for alt in alts:
        m = r.search(alt, sub)
        if m is not None:
            a_len = len(m.group())                             # length of match string

            # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
            if print_type == 3:
                print('  pat: {}\n  str: {}\n  len: {}'.format(alt, m.group(0), len(m.group(0))))

            if a_len >= keep_len:                              
                keep_len = a_len                               # sets alternate length to keep length
                exp = alt                                     # sets alt as keep variable

    # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
    if print_type == 3:
        print('  OUT: {}'.format(exp))                

    return exp

def get_states(exp):
    """counts number of subexpressions to be checked
       creates FSM"""

    # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
    if print_type == 3:
        print('\nGET STATES\n  EXP: {}'.format(exp))

    # List of possible subexpression regex matches
    m_gro = '\^*\((?:[^()]+|(?R))*+\)({.+?})*\$*'
    m_set = '\^*\[.+?\]({.+?})*\$*'
    m_alt = '\|'
    m_lit = '\^*[.\w]({.+?})*\$*|\$'


    # initialize capture list
    exp_list = []

    # loop through first level of subexpressions: 
    while exp != '':

        if r.match(m_gro, exp):
            _ = r.match(m_gro, exp).group(0)
            exp_list.append(_)
            exp = slice_string(_, exp)

        elif r.match(m_set, exp):
            _ = r.match(m_set, exp).group(0)
            exp_list.append(_)
            exp = slice_string(_, exp)



        elif r.match(m_alt, exp):
            _ = ''

        elif r.match(m_lit, exp):
            _ = r.match(m_lit, exp).group(0)
            exp_list.append(_)
            exp = slice_string(_, exp)

        else:
            print('ERROR getting states')
            break

    n_states = len(exp_list)


    # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
    if print_type == 3:
        print('GET STATES OUT\n  states:\n  {}\n  # of states: {}'.format(exp_list, n_states))


    return exp_list


def finite_state(exp_list, seq, level = 0, pattern_builder = '', iter_count = 0, pat_match = [], seq_match = []):


    # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
    if (print_type == 3):
        print('\nSTARTING MACHINE\n  EXP: {}\n  SEQ: {}\n  LEVEL: {}\n  matched: {}\n  pat_match: {}'.format(exp_list, seq, level, pattern_builder, pat_match))


    # patterns
    m_gro = '\^*\((?:[^()]+|(?R))*+\)({.+?})*\$*'
    m_set = '\^*\[.+?\]({.+?})*\$*'
    m_alt = '\|'
    m_squ = '\{(.),(.)\}'
    m_lit = '\^*[.\w]({.+?})*\$*|\$'


    # set state, n_state
    state = 0
    n_states = len(exp_list)
    #save_state = []
    #save_expression = []


    # temp exp
    local_seq = seq

    # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
    if print_type == 3:
        print('\n  >>>MACHINE START')



    # set failure cap so no endless loop
    failure_cap = 1000

    # since len(exp_list) returns + 1 over iteration (0 index) use the last 'state' as success state
    while state != n_states:

        for exp in exp_list:

            # iterations
            iter_count+=1

            # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
            if print_type == 3:
                print('  iteration count: {}'.format(iter_count))

            # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
            if print_type == 3:
                print('\n  evaluating: {}\n  for string: {}'.format(exp, local_seq))


            # alternation reset
            if len(alt_states(exp)) > 0:

                # get operand options
                operands = alt_states(exp)               
                # create temporary exp list
                temp_list = exp_list[state+1:]
                # add level
                level = level + 1                   

                # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
                if print_type == 3:
                    print('  ALT MATCH: {}\n  state: {}\n  opers returned: {}\n  level in: {}'.format(exp, state, operands, level))

                # compile local altneration
                for oper in operands:
                    # get substates
                    _ = get_states(oper)
                    # compile list
                    oper_list = _ + temp_list
                    # send to finite_state, sublevel                    
                    alt_status, pats = finite_state(oper_list, local_seq, level = level, pattern_builder=pattern_builder, iter_count=iter_count, pat_match=pat_match)
                    if alt_status == 'success':
                        return alt_status, pats


            # group cycle
            elif r.match(m_gro, exp) is not None:
                # get operand options
                operands = group_states(exp)
                # create temporary exp list
                temp_list = exp_list[state+1:]
                # add level
                level = level + 1

                # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
                if print_type == 3:
                    print('  GROUP MATCH: {}\n  state: {}\n  opers returned: {}\n  level in: {}'.format(exp, state, operands, level))

                # compile local
                oper_list = operands + temp_list
                # send to finite_state, sublevel
                group_status, pats = finite_state(oper_list, local_seq, level=level, pattern_builder=pattern_builder, iter_count=iter_count, pat_match=pat_match)
                if group_status == 'success':
                    return group_status, pats


            # quantifier reset
            elif r.search(m_squ, exp) is not None:
                # get operand options
                operands = quant_states(exp)
                # create temporary exp list
                temp_list = exp_list[state+1:]
                # add level
                level = level + 1

                # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
                if print_type == 3:
                    print('  QUANT MATCH: {}\n  state: {}\n  opers returned: {}\n  level in: {}'.format(exp, state, operands, level))

                # compile local
                for oper in reversed(operands):
                    # compile list
                    oper_list = [oper] + temp_list
                    # send to finite_state, sublevel
                    quant_status, pats = finite_state(oper_list, local_seq, level=level, pattern_builder=pattern_builder, iter_count=iter_count, pat_match=pat_match)
                    if quant_status == 'success':
                        return quant_status, pats


            # record literal
            elif r.match(exp, local_seq) is not None:
                # add to local pattern
                m = r.match(exp, local_seq).group(0)
                local_seq = slice_string(m, local_seq)

                # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
                if print_type == 3:
                    print('  state transition: {}\n  state {} ==> {} of {}'.format(exp, state, state+1, n_states))

                # iterate state for match
                pattern_builder = pattern_builder + exp
                pat_match = pat_match + [(exp, m)]
                state += 1
            elif r.match(exp, local_seq) is None:
                # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
                if print_type == 3:
                    print('  Return FAIL on {}, level: {}, state: {}'.format(exp, level, state))
                status = 'fail'
                return status, pattern_builder


            # machine success
            if state == n_states:

                # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
                if print_type == 3:
                    print('  MACHINE SUCCESS\n  level: {}\n  state: {}\n  exp: {}'.format(level, state, pattern_builder))

                status = 'success'
                return status, pat_match

            # timeout
            if iter_count == failure_cap:
                state = n_states

                # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
                if print_type == 3:
                    print('===============\nFAILURE CAP MET\n  level: {}\n  exp state: {}\n==============='.format(level, state))
                break

def group_states(exp):


    # patterns
    m_gro = '\^*\((?:[^()]+|(?R))*+\)({.+?})*\$*'
    m_set = '\^*\[.+?\]({.+?})*\$*'
    m_alt = '\|'
    m_squ = '\{(.),(.)\}'
    m_lit = '\^*[.\w]({.+?})*\$*'

    ret_list = []

    # iterate over groups
    groups = r.finditer(m_gro, exp)

    for gr in groups:
        _ = strip_nest(gr.group())      

        # alternation reset
        if r.search(m_alt, _):
            ret_list.append(_)

        else:
            _ = get_states(_)
            for thing in _:
                ret_list.append(thing)

    return(ret_list)

def quant_states(exp):


    # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
    if print_type == 4:
        print('\nGET QUANT STATES\n  EXP: {}'.format(exp))

    squ_opr = '(.+)\{.,.\}'
    m_squ = '\{(.),(.)\}'

    # create states
    states_list = []    

    # get operand
    operand_obj = r.finditer(squ_opr, exp)
    for match in operand_obj:
        operand = match.group(1)

    # get repetitions
    fa = r.findall(m_squ, exp)
    for m, n in fa:
        # loop through range
        for x in range(int(m), (int(n)+1)):
            # construct string
            _ = operand + '{' + str(x) + '}'
            # append to list
            states_list.append(_)

    # >>>PRINTOUT<<<
    if print_type == 4:
        print('  QUANT OUT: {}\n'.format(states_list))

    return states_list

%%time

print_type = 1
"""0:    
   1: includes input
   2: 
   3: all output prints on """


dataframe_counting = 0
for x in range(len(df)):

    try:
        df_expression = df.iloc[x, 2]
        df_subsequence = df.iloc[x, 1]

        # call function
        identify_submatches(df_expression, df_subsequence)
        print(dataframe_counting)
        dataframe_counting += 1
    except:
        pass
```

***Output Return Examples***

*Output values (i.e. subexpression & index set) are **tab delimited***.

```
Expression Input: [KR]{1,4}[KR].[KR]W.
Sequence Input: TRQARRNRRRRWRERQRQIH
Subequence Match: RRRRWR

    [KR]{1} (7, 8)
    [KR]    (8, 9)
    .   (9, 10)
    [KR]    (10, 11)
    W   (11, 12)
    .   (12, 13)
2270

Expression Input: [KR]{1,4}[KR].[KR]W.
Sequence Input: TASQRRNRRRRWKRRGLQIL
Subequence Match: RRRRWK

    [KR]{1} (7, 8)
    [KR]    (8, 9)
    .   (9, 10)
    [KR]    (10, 11)
    W   (11, 12)
    .   (12, 13)
2271

Expression Input: [KR]{1,4}[KR].[KR]W.
Sequence Input: TRKARRNRRRRWRARQKQIS
Subequence Match: RRRRWR

    [KR]{1} (7, 8)
    [KR]    (8, 9)
    .   (9, 10)
    [KR]    (10, 11)
    W   (11, 12)
    .   (12, 13)
2272

Expression Input: [KR]{1,4}[KR].[KR]W.
Sequence Input: LDFPSKKRKRSRWNQDTMEQ
Subequence Match: KKRKRSRWN

    [KR]{4} (5, 9)
    [KR]    (9, 10)
    .   (10, 11)
    [KR]    (11, 12)
    W   (12, 13)
    .   (13, 14)
2273

Expression Input: [KR]{1,4}[KR].[KR]W.
Sequence Input: ASQPPSKRKRRWDQTADQTP
Subequence Match: KRKRRWD

    [KR]{2} (6, 8)
    [KR]    (8, 9)
    .   (9, 10)
    [KR]    (10, 11)
    W   (11, 12)
    .   (12, 13)
2274

Expression Input: [KR]{1,4}[KR].[KR]W.
Sequence Input: GGATSSARKNRWDETPKTER
Subequence Match: RKNRWD

    [KR]{1} (7, 8)
    [KR]    (8, 9)
    .   (9, 10)
    [KR]    (10, 11)
    W   (11, 12)
    .   (12, 13)
2275

Expression Input: [KR]{1,4}[KR].[KR]W.
Sequence Input: PTPGASKRKSRWDETPASQM
Subequence Match: KRKSRWD

    [KR]{2} (6, 8)
    [KR]    (8, 9)
    .   (9, 10)
    [KR]    (10, 11)
    W   (11, 12)
    .   (12, 13)
2276

Expression Input: [VMILF][MILVFYHPA][^P][TASKHCV][AVSC][^P][^P][ILVMT][^P][^P][^P][LMTVI][^P][^P][LMVCT][ILVMCA][^P][^P][AIVLMTC]
Sequence Input: LLNAATALSGSMQYLLNYVN
Subequence Match: LLNAATALSGSMQYLLNYV

    [VMILF] (0, 1)
    [MILVFYHPA] (1, 2)
    [^P]    (2, 3)
    [TASKHCV]   (3, 4)
    [AVSC]  (4, 5)
    [^P]    (5, 6)
    [^P]    (6, 7)
    [ILVMT] (7, 8)
    [^P]    (8, 9)
    [^P]    (9, 10)
    [^P]    (10, 11)
    [LMTVI] (11, 12)
    [^P]    (12, 13)
    [^P]    (13, 14)
    [LMVCT] (14, 15)
    [ILVMCA]    (15, 16)
    [^P]    (16, 17)
    [^P]    (17, 18)
    [AIVLMTC]   (18, 19)
2277

Expression Input: [VMILF][MILVFYHPA][^P][TASKHCV][AVSC][^P][^P][ILVMT][^P][^P][^P][LMTVI][^P][^P][LMVCT][ILVMCA][^P][^P][AIVLMTC]
Sequence Input: IFEASKKVTNSLSNLISLIG
Subequence Match: IFEASKKVTNSLSNLISLI

    [VMILF] (0, 1)
    [MILVFYHPA] (1, 2)
    [^P]    (2, 3)
    [TASKHCV]   (3, 4)
    [AVSC]  (4, 5)
    [^P]    (5, 6)
    [^P]    (6, 7)
    [ILVMT] (7, 8)
    [^P]    (8, 9)
    [^P]    (9, 10)
    [^P]    (10, 11)
    [LMTVI] (11, 12)
    [^P]    (12, 13)
    [^P]    (13, 14)
    [LMVCT] (14, 15)
    [ILVMCA]    (15, 16)
    [^P]    (16, 17)
    [^P]    (17, 18)
    [AIVLMTC]   (18, 19)
2278

Expression Input: [VMILF][MILVFYHPA][^P][TASKHCV][AVSC][^P][^P][ILVMT][^P][^P][^P][LMTVI][^P][^P][LMVCT][ILVMCA][^P][^P][AIVLMTC]
Sequence Input: IYEKAKEVSSALSKVLSKID
Subequence Match: IYEKAKEVSSALSKVLSKI

    [VMILF] (0, 1)
    [MILVFYHPA] (1, 2)
    [^P]    (2, 3)
    [TASKHCV]   (3, 4)
    [AVSC]  (4, 5)
    [^P]    (5, 6)
    [^P]    (6, 7)
    [ILVMT] (7, 8)
    [^P]    (8, 9)
    [^P]    (9, 10)
    [^P]    (10, 11)
    [LMTVI] (11, 12)
    [^P]    (12, 13)
    [^P]    (13, 14)
    [LMVCT] (14, 15)
    [ILVMCA]    (15, 16)
    [^P]    (16, 17)
    [^P]    (17, 18)
    [AIVLMTC]   (18, 19)
2279

Expression Input: [VMILF][MILVFYHPA][^P][TASKHCV][AVSC][^P][^P][ILVMT][^P][^P][^P][LMTVI][^P][^P][LMVCT][ILVMCA][^P][^P][AIVLMTC]
Sequence Input: IYKAAKDVTTSLSKVLKNIN
Subequence Match: IYKAAKDVTTSLSKVLKNI

    [VMILF] (0, 1)
    [MILVFYHPA] (1, 2)
    [^P]    (2, 3)
    [TASKHCV]   (3, 4)
    [AVSC]  (4, 5)
    [^P]    (5, 6)
    [^P]    (6, 7)
    [ILVMT] (7, 8)
    [^P]    (8, 9)
    [^P]    (9, 10)
    [^P]    (10, 11)
    [LMTVI] (11, 12)
    [^P]    (12, 13)
    [^P]    (13, 14)
    [LMVCT] (14, 15)
    [ILVMCA]    (15, 16)
    [^P]    (16, 17)
    [^P]    (17, 18)
    [AIVLMTC]   (18, 19)
2280
```

Data from:
ELM (The Eukaryotic Linear Motif resource for Functional Sites in Proteins) 2020. Retrieved from http://elm.eu.org/searchdb.html

Comment: Although, you did a very long work, but I fear that OP might have or could have some regex having sets like `{}`, `[^]`, `()`, etc. So, I guess this will not be able identify each part of regex!

Comment: I assume there will be some patterns that fail - the routine is designed for easy expansion on the initial catch - all I or OP would need to do is add another conditional catch to move that unique sub-pattern down it's own specific pipeline! In the `sequencer` function under *# catches* is where additional cases go.

Comment: Here's a list of cases I noted that will probably need to be added to the conditional catch: escapes, repetition qualifiers, flags.

Most immediately the initial patterns to catch sets will probably need to be adjusted to catch sets + repetition qualifiers. The current demo string has the negation character [^] so that should be fine since it will either be inside or outside of a set (sans MULTILINE text)...¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thank a lot, there's a ton of work in what you've done! I was just wondering if you meant `p_no_set` to be `"'(\[\^.+\])"`, in parallel with p_set?

Comment: @GregSlodkowicz That was my 'attempt' at differentiating between character grouping (i.e. catch either sets or no sets). I've updated the code a bit to attempt to follow the logic of the regex machine but I wasn't able to get there fully (stuck on recursion as a result of .{m, n}. Anyhow, hope this helps!

Comment: @RahulVerma check updated answer - I've added additional if statements and sub-functions that provide a better checking process. Now the function checks the match for either: group, set, or literal (and .) using unique expressions. The expressions used to check include optional capture for ^ $ and the {} used as repetition qualifier.

Comment: @RahulVerma my 3 current issues with code: 1.) Trouble with recursive expressions relative to capture (i.e. .{3, 5} my current function cannot evaluate when to recurse and try a different variable). 2.) My function does not handle nested groups well (i.e. having to use essentially the same function on the subexpression if group is nested. 3.) Evaluating nested alternation: I don't have a good logical expression to capture when alternation is nested within a group.

Comment: My suggestion would be to stay positive and wait for the OP response to your edit, as in the question, OP hadn't cleared what kind of "289 RegEx" he has. Also, if you would ask me to describe the question in one line, then I would say: "how to design a RegEx engine", as we're asked to break _complex regex into simpler parts_ and then tell what each _simple part_ matches in the string.

Comment: Regarding the scraping part: Websites don't like scraping because you are causing traffic which costs them money. However not all online regex analyzers require an active internet connection. The processing is done on your browser client. If you dig deeper you might find the relevant javascript at which point you can just execute the javascript with your parameters and get a raw output of what was matched with what.

Comment: @RahulVerma Good suggestions, ty! On restructuring the question statement: I might actually be losing track of OP's goal and moving the question that way with my answer.

Comment: @TinNguyen Thanks - that's a good suggestion; I'll inspect the code from a few online debuggers and see if it provides some insight!

Comment: Not sure if I should keep editing the same answer or should have added as a new answer? Sorry if I'm causing trash posts; am new(er) to stackoverflow. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract *the positions of string* matched by each part of regex, then you should cover them up with `()` to make each piece a **capturing group**. Without doing so, you wouldn't be able to analyze the positions matched by each part of regex.

```
([DSTE])([^P])([^DEWHFYC])(D)([GSAN])
```

Now, you can see that each part is separated. So, *each part of regex* can be extracted using another regex

```
\((.*?)(?=\)(?:\(|$))
```

**Bonus:** You can also extract the *part of text matched* by each part of regex.

So, use [*`re.search(pattern, text, flags = 0)`*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#performing-matches) method to get the desired data, which is as follows

```
import re

text = 'ABCSGADAZZZ'
theRegex = r'([DSTE])([^P])([^DEWHFYC])(D)([GSAN])'

r1 = re.compile(r'\((.*?)(?=\)(?:\(|$))') # each part extractor
r2 = re.compile(theRegex) # your regex
grps = r1.findall(theRegex) # parts of regex
m = re.search(r2, text)

for i in range(len(grps)):
    print( 'Regex: {} | Match: {} | Range: {}'.format(grps[i], m.group(i+1), m.span(i+1)) )
```

[Live Example](https://rextester.com/SVEJZ91304)

Comment: This seems to be reducing the problem an equally complex one of how to decide where to put the match groups. But within this framework, the solution would be to find groups which cannot be split further. E.g. "([DSTE)" is not a meaningful group. "([DSTE])([^P])" is a group that can be split into "([DSTE])" and "([^P])" (which cannot be split further). Doing this programmatically is what I'm after.

Comment: @GregSlodkowicz: As you've said you want to see what was matched by each part of regex, so I guess it would be best, if you choose the parts by yourself (bcoz, I don't think regexes are much larger than 100 words, in general). However, if you want to do it programmatically, then I could think further. BTW, I don't feel that it is very hard to choose where to place "captures". Is it?

Comment: I have 289 regexs which is why I'm trying to avoid doing things by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seeing an regex engine with such capabilities made public in it's API. Or haven't been aware of such API. Maybe there is one, but not necessary in *R* or *Python*.

But anyway it's not that simple as I thing you think it is.

Consider regex `/(a(b*))*/` over `"abbabbb"` the `b*` part matches more than just a single substring. And on a contrary there can be a substring that is matched by more than just one part of some regex.

Even if your regexes are "fairly simple"... are they **all** really that simple as the one in the question?

As others already mentioned you can use capturing groups to find out which group matches what, but for that you'd need to edit regexes and track indecies of groups by yourself. Or, yes, write your own parser. Because regexes can't parse regexes - they are not powerful enough for their own grammar.

...Well, maybe there is a way to automatically and easily parse and modify all your regexes (to add capturing groups) if they are really simple and more or less uniform. But it's impossible to tell given the only one example of your regexes.

...But probably you're asking a wrong question: 
https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

> One trap that many posters fall into is to ask how to achieve some “small” aim, but never say what the larger aim is. Often the smaller aim is either impossible or rarely a good idea – instead, a different approach is needed

**Update:**

I've changes your example string and regex a little to account for `P{1,3}` case you've mentioned in the comments

Here is the code to modify your `regex`es and to get the output you want:

```py
import re

orig_re = "[DSTE]{1,1}[^P][^DEWHFYC]DP{1,3}[GSAN]"
mod_re = r'((\[.*?\]|.)(\{.*?\})?)'
groups = re.findall(mod_re, orig_re)
print("parts of regex:", [g[0] for g in groups])
new_regex_str = re.sub(mod_re, r'(\1)', orig_re)
print("new regex with capturing groups:", new_regex_str)
new_re = re.compile(new_regex_str)
str = "ABCSGADPPAZZZSGADPA"
matches = new_re.finditer(str)
for m in matches:
    print( '----------')
    for g in range(len(groups)):
        print('#{}: {} -- {}'.format(g, groups[g][0], m.span(g+1)))
```

It'll give you:

```
parts of regex: ['[DSTE]{1,1}', '[^P]', '[^DEWHFYC]', 'D', 'P{1,3}', '[GSAN]']
new regex with capturing groups: ([DSTE]{1,1})([^P])([^DEWHFYC])(D)(P{1,3})([GSAN])
----------
#0: [DSTE]{1,1} -- (3, 4)
#1: [^P] -- (4, 5)
#2: [^DEWHFYC] -- (5, 6)
#3: D -- (6, 7)
#4: P{1,3} -- (7, 9)
#5: [GSAN] -- (9, 10)
----------
#0: [DSTE]{1,1} -- (13, 14)
#1: [^P] -- (14, 15)
#2: [^DEWHFYC] -- (15, 16)
#3: D -- (16, 17)
#4: P{1,3} -- (17, 18)
#5: [GSAN] -- (18, 19)
```

Also in JS

```js
const orig_re = "[DSTE]{1,1}[^P][^DEWHFYC]DP{1,3}[GSAN]"
const mod_re = /((\[.*?\]|.)(\{.*?\})?)/g
groups = [...orig_re.matchAll(mod_re)].map(g=>g[0])
console.log("parts of regex:", groups)
const new_re = orig_re.replace(mod_re, "($1)")
console.log("new regex with capturing groups:", new_re)
const str = "ABCSGADPPAZZZSGADPA"
matches = str.matchAll(new_re)
for(const m of matches) {
    console.log('----------')
    let pos = m.index
    groups.forEach((g,i) => console.log(`#${i}: ${g} -- (${pos},${pos += m[i+1].length})`))
}
```

Comment: I didn't mention the 'larger aim' because I felt it's fairly domain-specific. Each regex defines a biologically meaningful part of a protein sequence (a sequence 'motif'). Once I have matches for a motif in a protein sequence, I would like to know which position in the sequence corresponds to what part of the motif. So I suppose the regex's are simple in the sense that you expect each part of it to generally match one position, unlike your example with nested groups (but there are cases like "between 1 and 3 prolines" which would correspond to something like "P{1,3}"). Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

With the [stringr](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/) package, you should be able to combine like so:

```
> stringr::str_match_all(string = "ABCSGADAZZZ",
                         pattern = "[DSTE][^P][^DEWHFYC]D[GSAN]")
[[1]]
     [,1]   
[1,] "SGADA"
> stringr::str_locate_all(string = "ABCSGADAZZZ",
                          pattern = "[DSTE][^P][^DEWHFYC]D[GSAN]")
[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     4   8
```

and then combine function outputs or write a simple wrapper-function

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to give the location of the entire match, rather than individual tokens within the regex? From this and other responses I'm realising that what's at the core of my question is actually splitting a regex into it's constituent parts.